# Why is my Loop event handler not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to set the node sharedobject to trigger for each a href click event, but for some reasons, only the first one is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    file_container.innerHTML = file_container.innerHTML + `<a id="file${i}" href="#" class="list-group-item">${files[i]}</a>`;
    document.getElementById('file' + i).onclick = (function (i) {
      require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').filename = files[i].replace('.tnb','');
      window.location = "login.html";
    })(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `onclick` assignment should accept a function but what your code is doing is (immediately) executing a function and then returning the result of this execution to `onclick`.

Since you're using `let`, which has block scope, there's no need to use an IIFE, you can just return a function as the handler, not execute it:

```
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  file_container.innerHTML = file_container.innerHTML + `<a id="file${i}" href="#" class="list-group-item">${files[i]}</a>`;
  document.getElementById('file' + i).onclick = function () { // <-- return the click handler for each element
    require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').filename = files[i].replace('.tnb','');
    window.location = "login.html";
  };
}
```

As suggested by Alnitak in the comments, using forEach would create a separate scope and eliminate the need for the IIFE:

```
files.forEach(function (file, i) {
  file_container.innerHTML = file_container.innerHTML + `<a id="file${i}" href="#" class="list-group-item">${file}</a>`;
  document.getElementById('file' + i).onclick = function () {
    require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').filename = file.replace('.tnb','');
    window.location = "login.html";
  };
});
```

Comment: why do we need IIFE at all?

Comment: to maintain the reference to the proper `i`, when accessing the files array

Comment: The first argument of onclick is the event, so you can't just pass i to it

Comment: A `.forEach` iteration over `files` would provide a bound version of `i` to use in the callback far more easily, though (per my answer) without using any IIFEs

Comment: @nem035 : By using `let` instead of `var`, we already achieved that.

Comment: @A.J yeah, I caught that right before you commented :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're binding async callbacks relative to an array then it's far easier to use `.forEach`:

```
files.forEach((file, i) => {
    file_container.innerHTML = file_container.innerHTML + `<a id="file${i}" href="#" class="list-group-item">${file}</a>`;
    document.getElementById('file' + i).onclick = () => {
        require('electron').remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').filename = file.replace('.tnb','');
        window.location = "login.html";
    });
});
```